# If NP-complete, prove another is also NP-complete

Tags: computer-science, np-complete

I've been trying to work on this problem but I don't really know where to start and can't find any resources online. Would it be possible for someone to guide me through step by step.

[image]

Comment: You want to find a _many-one reduction_ from VC to HS. Your textbook (or whichever other material you're learning form) ought to explain how that works, with plenty of examples, since such reductions are at the core of what it _means_ to be NP-complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices in VC "cover" every $edge$ (u, v) in G
This just means that every $edge$ (u, v) has at least one of its $vertices$ (u or v) in VC

The elements in HS "cover" every $subset$ $S_i$ in U
This just means that every $subset$ $S_i$ has at least one of its $elements$ in HS

Notice how the problems are "similar"
The $edges$ in the VC problem correspond to $subsets$ in the HC problem
The $vertices$ in the VC problem correspond to the $elements$ in the HS problem

This gives an idea for how to reduce VC to HS.
For every edge (u, v) in G, add the subset {u, v} to U.

To prove that our reduction works, we have to prove:
$\quad$G has a VC of size $\le k \iff$ U has a HS of size $\le k$

G has a VC of size $\le k$
$\quad \Rightarrow$ every $edge$ (u, v) in G has at least one of its $vertices$ (u or v) in VC
$\quad \Rightarrow$ every $subset$ {u, v} in U has at least one of its $elements$ (u or v) in HS  (by setting HS = VC)
$\quad\Rightarrow$ U has a HS of size $\le k$

U has a HS of size $\le k$
$\quad \Rightarrow$ every $subset$ {u, v} in U has at least one of its $elements$ (u or v) in HS
$\quad \Rightarrow$ every $edge$ (u, v) in G has at least one of its $vertices$ (u or v) in VC   (by setting VC = HS)
$\quad\Rightarrow$ G has a VC of size $\le k$